# Android: webview and soft keyboard with numbers and math operators

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard

I have a WebView with form fields that can contain only numbers and simple mathematical operations (divide/multiple signs, '/' to type in fraction etc) - user should be able to type a simple mathematical formula.

If I designate  in the HTML I get numeric keypad without math operators. I also tried using android:digits in XML, but as expected this doesn't work with WebView.

Is there a simple solution to my problem or I have to implement custom soft keyboard?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the exact same question.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: I didn't. Going with the default keyboard